Calculate Column and Row Totals in Oracle BI Publisher rtf Template
I am working on a cashflow report and I am stuck at calculating row and column totals. I have explored pivot tables, but I am not keen on using them as they convert null number value into 0. And the client do not want that to happen. I am getting following row totals and the formula <?if:ACCOUNTED_NET_CHAR!=' '?><?sum(current-group()/ACCOUNTED_NET)?><?end if?> does not evaluate correctly

I have attached the sample xml and rtf template, any help will be greatly appreciated.
EDIT:
That is what I would like to get from this rtf template:

The Totals (in the last row) should sum up all the non-null values in the group and show the total for each month column and the Totals column as well. The Totals column should sum up all the non-null values for each account.

Docs you shared are not 100% public, please update access. Also, Do you have an example mockup of what you expect to see?

I have given full access for the files. Thank you for letting me know.

Have you read the BI Publisher Report Designers Guide? I've never personally done something with dynamic columns like this. I recall there is a section in the guide about this. You may have to use variables for totals.
